# KSH: Spread commands equally over time

Tags: performance, shell, unix, ksh

I'm working on a ksh performance script. It takes the following options:
- i (interval time)
- p (messages per interval)
- t (total messages)

So for example: "script -i 1 -p 2 -t 10" means 2 messages per second to a maximum of 10.

This is working, but the script does not yet equally spread the messages over the given interval time. In this example the script should execute the second command after 0.5 seconds, not before.

Is it possible to do this easily?

In short, this is what I have so far:

```
typeset -i i=0
typeset -i n=0

while [ $i -lt $TOTAAL ]; do
   while [ $n -lt $PERINT ]; do

      # execute this command

      n=$((n+1))
   done

   i=`expr $i + $PERINT`
   # Reset n
   n=0
   # Wait interval time
   sleep $INTERVAL
done
```

-i: $INTERVAL is an integer (0, 1, 2...) and not calculated in any way. I have done input checks to prevent input the script does not expect.

-t: $TOTAAL

-p: $PERINT

Comment: 1. If you can do `n=$(( n+1 ))` you can also do `i=$(( i+PERINT ))`.   2. With an integer interval, why expect 0.5s. between messages/commands?

Comment: I don't know. I hope there is a way because the version of sleep I have to use, does only support integers.

Comment: ksh93 (the *official* ksh) has had subsecond sleep for quite a while.  Which platform is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [serverfault question 340838](https://serverfault.com/questions/340838/what-version-of-ksh-ships-with-aix-5-3) Aix 5.3 ships with a separate ksh93 binary in /usr/bin/ksh93.

This will have subsecond `sleep` and floating point arithmetic. Watch out for fence-post errors, when calculating the interval.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it if ksh93 is present on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Henk Langeveld, I found out ksh93 was pre-installed. This is the new script. It seems to work fine.

```
typeset -i i=0
typeset -i n=0

while [ $i -lt $TOTAAL ]; do
   while [ $n -lt $PERINT ]; do

      # execute this command

      sleep $VERDELING
      n=$((n+1))
   done

   i=$((i+PERINT))
   # Reset n
   n=0
done
```

These are some of the checks I use. I translated the error-messages.

```
if [[ $PERINT -gt $TOTAAL ]]; then
  echo "[[31mFOUT[0m] Messages per interval cannot be greater then total amount"; exit
fi

VERGELIJK=`echo "scale=1; $TOTAAL / $PERINT" | bc`
if [[ $VERGELIJK = *.[1-9]* ]]; then
  echo "[[31mFOUT[0m] Messages per interval has to be a multiple of the total amount"; exit
fi

VERDELING=`echo "scale=2; $INTERVAL / $PERINT" | bc`
```